# Eclipse preference page, Dialog with title Authorizing with Eclipse.org

Tags: java, eclipse

When I create my own preference page to rcp application and open my eclipse application runtime-> windows->preference->{newly created preference page}-> a dialog will be displayed, with the title Authorizing with Eclipse.org.

Could anyone help me how to disable this dialog from showing?
My eclipse version is Oxygen.

preference page popup dialog to login eclipse account:

[image: preference page popup dialog to login eclipse account]

LoginDialog same as open eclipse user storage:

[image: LoginDialog same as open eclipse user storage]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Never seen this dialog. It is not normally displayed for a preference page. Show us your preference page. What does [Eclipse plugin spy](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html#pluginspy) say the dialog is?

Comment: it's a loginDialog, which can also be opened by Eclipse User Storage -> Open My Account

Comment: I don't use Eclipse User Storage (don't even have it installed) so I can't help.

Comment: thanks for your help! I think the dialog will disappear when I disinstall the eclipse user storage.

Comment: Do you have a connected account for the Eclipse User Storage? _Window > Preferences: General > User Storage Service > Linked Accounts_

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you accidentally clicked on the "Oomph preference recorder" button. It's the red middle button in the bottom left of the preferences window. Click it again to disable it.

Comment: But If i need oomph record enabled and want to get rid of this pop-up? is it possible? Yes, I found it. Oomph Preferences -> Setup tasks - Preference Synchronizer -> Synch with eclipse.org disabled

Comment: Thanks a lot for saving me